# Vanilla Materialize -- AM option not available in IE

Tags: jquery, materialize, timepicker

I've found that the Time Picker within Materialize does not include the AM option. Not selecting PM will auto-select AM, however there is no way to go back to AM if you've selected PM.

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html#time-picker -- Click the lunchtime input when using IE.

Has anyone found this? Is there a way to report this to Materialize team, or a way for a quick fix until another update?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Sorry, IE 11 here.

Comment: You can report this problem as an issue here : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues